# how to populate a Dictionary list of class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary

sorry for the title i don't see a better one for my problem.

In VB.NET i have a dictionary(key, list(of )) to add element in the dictionary i create a temporary list and add the list to the dictionary. when i finish to add it i clear the list. But doing that it also clear the value i add to the dict.
I can't figure out why

here is my code :

```
Public Class MesuresVar


Private _Moyenne_Comp As Single



Public Shared DicOfControl As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of CtrlItem))  
Public Event VariableChanged(ByVal Val As Object, UpdateCtrl As String)


Public Sub New()
    Dim Tmp_List As New List(Of CtrlItem)
    Dim f As New frmAcc
    Tmp_List.Add(New CtrlItem With {.Ctrl = f.L_Moy_G, .prop = "Text"})
    Tmp_List.Add(New CtrlItem With {.Ctrl = f.GaugeSACCG, .prop = "Mesure"})
    DicOfControl.Add("_Moyenne_Comp", Tmp_List)
    Tmp_List.Clear()

End Sub

Public Property Moyenne_Comp As Single
    Get
        Return _Moyenne_Comp
    End Get
    Set(value As Single)
        _Moyenne_Comp = value

        RaiseEvent VariableChanged(_Moyenne_Comp.ToString, "_Moyenne_Comp")
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Thanks

Comment: Dont clear it.  `Tmp_List` will go out of scope without messing with the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

When you add Tmp_List to the dictionary, you are not adding a copy of the list.You are adding a reference to the list. The temp list you clear is the same as the temp list in the dictionary.

There is no need to clear the list. Just let the Tmp_List variable go out of scope when the constructor ends.

Comment: That's what i think. But is there a way to change that and add the val and not the ref to the object?

Comment: If you want to add multiple lists to the dictionary in the constructor, just point Tmp_List to a new instance: Tmp_List = New List(Of CtrlItem)

Answer (score 1):

The list you add is the same as the list you clear. Don't clear it.

```
Public Sub New()
    Dim Tmp_List As New List(Of CtrlItem)
    Dim f As New frmAcc
    Tmp_List.Add(New CtrlItem With {.Ctrl = f.L_Moy_G, .prop = "Text"})
    Tmp_List.Add(New CtrlItem With {.Ctrl = f.GaugeSACCG, .prop = "Mesure"})
    DicOfControl.Add("_Moyenne_Comp", Tmp_List)
End Sub
```

This code would also do the same thing, might help you understand what is happening.

```
Public Sub New()
    Dim Tmp_List As New List(Of CtrlItem)
    Dim f As New frmAcc
    DicOfControl.Add("_Moyenne_Comp", Tmp_List)
    Tmp_List.Add(New CtrlItem With {.Ctrl = f.L_Moy_G, .prop = "Text"})
    Tmp_List.Add(New CtrlItem With {.Ctrl = f.GaugeSACCG, .prop = "Mesure"})
End Sub
```

Comment: my main goal was to add other key to the dictionnary by using the same list. That's why i want to clear it....

Comment: @got_fr the list will be in the dictionary so you can reuse it if desired; the same list object variable (Tmp_List) can be used elsewhere with the same or different contents.  (Thats why they are called *variables*...they can vary) `Tmp_List` can be used as a var with different contents later

Comment: @got_fr if you add the same list for other dictionary key, then you'll end up with the same exact list for both key (adding a CtrlItem in one will add it to the other). If you want two list with different content, then you need to create a new list by using the New keyword.

Comment: ... the dictionary isnt going to know the name of the temp var used to create the list if that is what you are worried about...try it

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
thanks all.

i rewrite a little bit my code to mix with what you told me andsomething i found clear...

here it is :

```
       DicOfControl.Add("_Moyenne_Comp", New List(Of CtrlItem))

    DicOfControl("_Moyenne_Comp").Add((New CtrlItem With {.Ctrl = frmAcc.L_Moy_G, .prop = "Text"}))
    DicOfControl("_Moyenne_Comp").Add((New CtrlItem With {.Ctrl = frmAcc.GaugeSACCG, .prop = "Mesure"}))
```

So no temporary variable (at least not seeing in the code ;-) )

Comment: That should result in a runtime error - you cant repeat Dictionary keys - the point of a Dictionary is that each key is unique

Comment: it works. I don't  repeat key the add is infact for the "list(of)". This is what i thought !